# Two supermartingales and a stopping time

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, martingales, stopping-times

I have the following task to do:

Let $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$ be two supermartingales on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ and $T$ be a stopping time regarding a filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)$ and $X_T \leq Y_T$ on $\{T< \infty\}$.

Define $Z_n = Y_n$ on $\{n<T\}$ and $Z_n = X_n$ on $\{T \leq n\}$.

Proof that $(Z_n)$ is a supermartingale.

I tried to use $Z_n = Y_nI_{\{n<T\}} + X_nI_{\{T\leq n\}}$ and plug that into $\mathbb{E}[Z_n|\mathcal{F_{n-1}}]$ and use some properties of the conditional expectation, but I don't seem to get to $\leq Z_{n-1}$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: On behalf of @hosam ahmad: this is a theorem 8.1 page 498 in *Probability: A Graduate Course* Authors: Gut, Allan

https://www.springer.com/la/book/9781441919854

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $X_T \leq Y_T$ implies that

$$\begin{align*} X_n 1_{\{T \leq n\}} = X_n 1_{\{T \leq n-1\}} + X_T 1_{\{T=n\}} &\leq X_n 1_{\{T \leq n-1\}}+ Y_T 1_{\{T =n\}} \\ &= X_n 1_{\{T \leq n-1\}}+ Y_n 1_{\{T =n\}}. \end{align*}$$

Thus,

$$Z_n \leq Y_{n} 1_{\{T \leq n-1\}^c} + X_n 1_{\{T \leq n-1\}}.$$

Now use that $(Y_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are supermartingales and the fact  that $\{T \leq n-1\} \in \mathcal{F}_{n-1}$ to conclude that

$$\mathbb{E}(Z_n \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}) \leq Z_{n-1}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have to ask how do you conclude $Z_n \leq Y_n 1_{\{T\leq n-1\}^c} + X_n1_{\{T\leq n-1\}}$? I have $Z_n \leq Y_n 1_{\{n\leq T\}} + X_n1_{\{T\leq n-1\}}$.

Comment: @tha That's exactly the same thing, isn't it? Note that $\{n \leq T\} = \{T \geq n\} = \{T \leq n-1\}^c$.

Comment: Oh yes, that was my fault. Everything is good, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

this is a theorem 8.1 page 498 in Probability: A Graduate Course
Authors: Gut, Allan

https://www.springer.com/la/book/9781441919854